# Git error in Windows 7: git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)

Tags: windows, git, git-clone

I am really new to git, but today, I need to create a repository on our WIN7 32bit box.

I go to here, and followed this, except the keys.

https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-CopSSH

The steps what I've made:

- Download Git for Windows and install it
- Created the hard links.
- Installed the CopSSH
- Add a user, called gituser, and set up a password.
- Activated the user in the CopSSH. But, at here, I turned off the Public key authentication.
- Created a new repository
- Added `C:\Git\cmd;C:\Git\bin;` to the `PATH` variable.

Now, when I want to clone the repository on my desktop, it asks the username / password. I write it, and I've get an error message:

*git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (38049 ms @ 2015.05.04. 17:30:45)
*

Can anybody tell me, what could be the problem? If it is possible, I do not want to create and setup the keys. This is for internal use in the local network.

Comment: did you check the permissions for gituser wrt the repository?

Comment: Yes. Windows added this `gituser` to the `users` group, but I've also added a permission to read, write, modify, to that folder.

Answer (score -1):

I know that is an old one, but I think it is very important for future users.
All I needed to do was to delete a file called index.lock in the .git directory.

Comment: That's not a good answer to this question as the usual behavior when that file is (erroneously) present is a message along the lines of "Another git process seems to be running in this repository", not "git did not exit cleanly".